# Can powers of a maximal ideal stabilize without vanishing?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$. Suppose that there exists some positive integer $k$ such that $m^k = m^{k+1}$.

Is necessarily $m^k = 0$ ?

If $m$ is finitely generated, this follows from Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: If $A$ is the integers in an algebraically closed valued field (for example an algebraic closure of the p-adic numbers or any discrete valued field) then $A$ is local and $m=m^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that one might try seems to be a counter-example to that:

$R=k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$

$\mathfrak m={(x_1,x_2,\dots)}, I=(x_1-x_2^2,x_2-x_3^2,x_3-x_4^2,\dots)\subset R$.

$A=(R/I)_{\mathfrak m}, m=\mathfrak m_{\mathfrak m}$.

Answer (score 6):

No:  $A = k[[T^{(1/n)}: n \in$ ℕ$]]$